# getting current angle and position from navigation stack

Tags: python, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there anyway to get the current angle and x and position from the navigation stack the robot is at? Please note that all my code is in python.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/87366/getting-current-angle-and-position-from-navigation-stack/) by [Massbuilder](https://answers.ros.org/users/6726/massbuilder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2013-10-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use TF to lookup the transform between your map origin and the robot. See the [Using Published Transforms](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Overview/Using%20Published%20Transforms#lookupTransform) tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Massbuilder](https://answers.ros.org/users/6726/massbuilder/) on 2013-10-07**:
thanks that will help with solving a slight problem with my odometry node.

**Comment by [Massbuilder](https://answers.ros.org/users/6726/massbuilder/) on 2013-10-08**:
I also need a position/angle the robot will need to go to. Which msg should I subscribe to to get it.

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2013-10-08**:
Are you referring to the goal sent to move_base? That is done with either an action call, or on the topic move_base_simple/goal.

**Comment by [Massbuilder](https://answers.ros.org/users/6726/massbuilder/) on 2013-10-08**:
more along the lines of the results from the navigation stack, my robot at the moment uses servos for navigation and I am not quite comfortable with speed control by changing pulse frequencies. I need something like a postion stamped to get distance to travel and orientation